# Bootstrap navbar brand left margin not overriding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to override the left margin of the bootstrap class `navbar-brand` like so

```
.navbar .navbar-brand{
  margin-left: 15px;
  background: url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Basic stuff right ? Well as I remember from my training is the class that is last in the list of classes, it's properties get set. Now in this case it just won't take my override in my `main.css` file. I've tried different selectors, different positions in the class list. I even tried different class names. As it is like always in CSS I'm probally missing something tiny small I can't seem to think of now or maybe it's something major I have never encountered before.

[image]
[image]

Anyway can someone point me in the right direction here ? This has been driving me nuts for the past 2 days now. I'll attach my files below.

[main.html](http://pastebin.com/NHHtRfJW) &
[main.css](http://pastebin.com/paMKG3VJ)

Comment: You can either be more specific on your CSS rules or just add `!important;` to overwrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely related to [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). You have a more specific selector that's setting that element's margin. You can confirm this by setting `margin-left: 15px!important;`

If the `margin-left` take effect after that, it's a specificity issue, if not you know it's something else.

You can resolve specificity issues by making your selectors more specific or other selectors less specific (or you can cheat it by putting your styles inline via `style` attribute or using `!important`).

Edit:
As you can see from your devtools screenshot, your class is definitely less specific than the one from Bootstrap. This should work:

```
@media (min-width:768px){
  .navbar > .container .navbar-brand,
  .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I kinda guessed that would be the problem. But the same happens now if I add a class there. My browsers just doesn't pick it up.

Comment: Yea, you'll definitely want to brush up on CSS specificity rules.  They're a HUGE pain, but they're definitely causing you your issues.  In addition to the other link I sent you, this is a pretty good article highlighting some things you can do: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Yeah it's seems. Like I said I'm trying the same with adding a brand class to the nav brand class `nav.navbar> .container-fluid .navbar-brand` but the browser just doesn't pick it up. I'm also wondering what the `>` token does. I have seen it before but I have never used it before

Comment: The `>` is the child selector. It selects immediate descendants. In this case, `nav.navbar > .container-fluid`, you're selecting `.container-fluid`'s, but only if they're immediate descendants of a `nav.navbar`. From there, you're selecting all descendants with the class `.navbar-brand`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
.navar div.container-fluid div.navbar-header a {
      margin-left: 15px;
      background: url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Let me know if it helped

Comment: No, it doesn't now the class is just not recognized by the browser. But the thing is , shouldn't the rules of specificity apply here ?

Answer (score 1):

Your override is not evaluated because there is a more specific css rule in bootstrap.css. You can try to make your css selector bit more specific.

Eg:

```
nav.navbar>container-fluid .navbar-brand{
  margin-left: 15px;
  background: url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Same question. Should the rules of specificity apply here ?

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

is less specific than

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

try

```
@media (min-width: 768px) 
.navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To specifically override a property copy the exact classes applied from the developer tools.. In your case which would be `.navbar>.container .navbar-brand .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand`.  So basically it will be

```
@media (min-width:768px){
.navbar>.container .navbar-brand .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand{
      margin-left: 15px;
   }
}
```

Another way is simply using `!important` after the property which you want to overwrite everything irrespective of `media queries`. This is not recommended unless you are sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use !important.

```
.navbar .navbar-brand{
margin-left:10% !important;
}
```